# Python Dataframe to existing Excel sheet overwriting data

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

Starting from this question:

[Output to excel file without overwriting sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713665/output-to-excel-file-without-overwriting-sheets)

I would like to **overwrite existing data in Excel**, but only starting on a certain row and column, **leaving there rest of the sheet intact**.

[image]

The Excel above would then turn into something like:

[image]

The code from the answer that is correct, on the linked question is this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize xlsx writer and open existing file

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3],
                    "b": [1,2,3]})

#The objective here is just to paste the dataframe on an existing Excel sheet
#and overwrite what is there, leaving unchanged the rest of the sheet.

df.to_excel(writer,
             sheet_name="Data",
             startrow=3,
             startcol=3)



writer.save()
```

I have the file "output_file" with 4 sheets and a lot of other data.

This code is overwriting the file with a new file. I would just like to add the dataframe to the spreadsheet "Data", starting on the specified row and column and leaving the rest of the "Data" spreadsheet untouched.

Thank you all.

Comment: So like it's working correctly?

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: Sorry for not having been clear. I have the file output_file with 4 sheets and a lot of other data. 
This code is overwriting the file with a new file. I would just like to add the dataframe to the sheet "Data", starting on the specified row and column.